# CSS just on mobile

Tags: css

I am trying to make and edit to my css just on the mobile side but it doesn't work.
If i don't include the @media it works on pc and mobile but if i put the @media it doesn't change anything on pc as it should not do but it also doesn't do anything on mobile.

```
@media (max-width: 991px)
#products .product-miniature .product-container div.left-block .product-image img, .featured-products .product-miniature .product-container div.left-block .product-image img, .product-accessories .product-miniature .product-container div.left-block .product-image img, .product-miniature .product-container div.left-block .product-image img, .category-products .product-miniature .product-container div.left-block .product-image img {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
}

@media (max-width: 991px)
#products .product-miniature, .featured-products .product-miniature, .product-accessories .product-miniature, .product-miniature, .category-products .product-miniature {
    height: 295px;
}
```

Comment: You missed the curly braces around the media block: `@media (...) { /* CSS goes here */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
    @media (max-width: 991px){
#products .product-miniature .product-container div.left-block .product-image img, .featured-products .product-miniature .product-container div.left-block .product-image img, .product-accessories .product-miniature .product-container div.left-block .product-image img, .product-miniature .product-container div.left-block .product-image img, .category-products .product-miniature .product-container div.left-block .product-image img {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
}
}
@media (max-width: 991px){
#products .product-miniature, .featured-products .product-miniature, .product-accessories .product-miniature, .product-miniature, .category-products .product-miniature {
    height: 295px;
}}
```

Comment: @Boldewyn It worked after putting the curly braces but it's weird that i have another css code that doesn't have the curly braces for `@media` but that piece of code does work only on mobile.

Comment: @Ciprian if you found my answer useful you can upvote it